# NPM update doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to update dependencies in subfolder, I have MERN stack app, there is a client folder with React code, when I want to update dependencies in client folder it does nothing, it looks like I write plain text..

```
PS C:\Users\userPC\Documents\Projects\reactapp\client> npm outdated
PS C:\Users\userPC\Documents\Projects\reactapp\client> npm update
PS C:\Users\userPC\Documents\Projects\reactapp\client> npm update
PS C:\Users\userPC\Documents\Projects\reactapp\client>
```

I can type `npm start`, it starts the app as expected..

Comment: This would help you https://www.carlrippon.com/upgrading-npm-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try that probably will work:

1. Clear the npm cache and if that doesn't work
2. Delete the node_modules folder and try again.

You can clear the cache by doing a `npm cache clean`.
You can delete the node modules folder using `rimraf node_modules`.